# Does sequence_length help performance of dynamic_rnn?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, machine-translation

In [Google's recent nmt tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt), they say this:

> Note that sentences have different lengths to avoid wasting computation, we tell dynamic_rnn the exact source sentence lengths through source_seqence_length

with this code: 
`encoder_outputs, encoder_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    encoder_cell, encoder_emb_inp,
    sequence_length=source_seqence_length, time_major=True)`

However, I was reading [dynamic_rnn's documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py) and it says:

> The parameter `sequence_length` is optional and is used to copy-through state
>     and zero-out outputs when past a batch element's sequence length. So it's more
>     for correctness than performance.

I'm just wondering if sequence_length really helps performance of dynamic_rnn, e.g. they do some kind of dynamic bucketing? If they do, is there any place where I can read more about it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure about performance, but from what I understand at least it's meant to help you keep your state accurate. Even if it iterates through the unnecessary (zeroed) steps, my understanding is that at least it won't update state those part of the zeroed sequences.